# Differences of Probability Mass Functions

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I'm bloody beginner in probability of math. and there are things that makes my mind confusing.

what's the differences of those?

and how i can read them?

1. $P[X|Y]$

2. $P_{X|Y}[X]$

3. $P_{X|Y}[x|y]$

 Here is another thing that i don't understand. $P[a|b]=\frac{P[a\cap b]}{P[b]}$
Isn't this just equal to $P[a|b]=P[a]$ since $P[a\cap b]= P[a]\times P[b]$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *more concise definitions* in measure theory, but roughly, *if* $X$ and $Y$ are random variables (or rather events measured by these random variables) in all of these then:

> •1. $\mathsf P[X\mid Y]$

This is the conditional probability of $X$ given $Y$.  It is a function of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, and is itself a random variable.

> •2. $P_{X\mid Y}[x]$

This is the conditional probability of $X=x$ given $Y$.  It is a function of the value $x$ and the random variable $Y$ and is itself a random variable.

> •3. $P_{X\mid Y} [x\mid y]$

This is the conditional probability of $X=x$ given $Y=y$.  It is a function of the values $x, y$.  It is itself a real value.

---

The product rule $\mathsf P(a\cap b) = P(a)\times P(b)$ holds *if and only if* $a$ and $b$ are independent.  Otherwise the conditional probability of $a$ given $b$ does not equal the unconditional probability of $a$, and the product rule is:

$$\mathsf P(a\cap b)= \mathsf P(a\mid b) \mathsf P(b)$$

*Example:*  For a single roll of the same die, let $a$ be the event that the result is an odd number ($1,3,5$), and let $b$ be the event that the result is a prime number ($2,3,5$).  Then the conjunction is the event that the result is both odd and a prime number ($3,5$).

$$\mathsf P(a)=1/2, \mathsf P(b)=1/2, \mathsf P(a\cap b) = 1/3 , \mathsf P(a\mid b)=2/3$$

Answer (score 1):

The first is read as "The probability of given values of $x$, given that $y$ is the specified value of $Y$".  The second has the same meaning but the author has chosen to emphasize that $Y$ is some fixed value so this is just a function of $x$.

The third seems to be utterly redundant; I have never seen that notation.

As to your question, if $a$ and $b$ are independent variables, then yes,
$P(a|b) = P(a)$.  But if they are correlated, then that won't necessarily be true.

For example, let X be the number rolled on a red die, Y be the number rolled on a blue die, and let's say we know that the total rolled on those two was 7.  Then 
$P(X=5)$ is $\frac{1}{6}$ but P$X=5|Y=2)$ is $1$.

Comment: Actually the 3rd one that i really needed to understand, its given in my HW twice